# How to understand directly present, indirectly present, present, and associated in java annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

In java doc of [AnnotatedElement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html), I read the term : **directly present, indirectly present, present, and associated**, but I couldn't understand their meaning.

For example, in the doc it says :

> An annotation A is directly present on an element E if E has a RuntimeVisibleAnnotations or RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations or RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations attribute, and the attribute contains A.

But I don't know what **RuntimeVisibleAnnotations attribute** is and what's the meaning of "**the attribute contains A**".

Can someone give some examples to show their difference, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Attributes (e.g. `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`)

The mentioned attributes are part of the class file format. For instance, the `RuntimeVisibleAnnotaitons` attribute is described by [§4.7.16 of the *Java Virtual Machine Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16):

> The  `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`  attribute  is  a  variable-length  attribute  in  the attributes table of a `ClassFile`, `field_info`, or `method_info` structure (§4.1,§4.5,   §4.6). The `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` attribute records run-time visible annotations on the declaration of the corresponding class, field, or method.
>
> There   may   be   at   most   one   `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`   attribute   in   the attributes table of a `ClassFile`, `field_info`, or `method_info` structure.
>
> *[...]*

You can see this attribute by inspecting the byte code via `javap`. For example, this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface // has runtime retention
public interface Foo {
  void bar(); // satisfy functional interface requirements
}
```

Gives this:

```
public interface Foo
  minor version: 0
  major version: 58
  flags: (0x0601) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT
  this_class: #1                          // Foo
  super_class: #3                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 1, attributes: 2
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             // Foo
   #2 = Utf8               Foo
   #3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               bar
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = Utf8               SourceFile
   #8 = Utf8               Foo.java
   #9 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
  #10 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/FunctionalInterface;
{
  public abstract void bar();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0401) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
}
SourceFile: "Foo.java"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #10()
    java.lang.FunctionalInterface
```

You can see the `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` attribute for the class (interface) `Foo` at the bottom. That attribute contains a single entry: `java.lang.FunctionalInterface`. That means said annotation is directly present on `Foo`.

---

## Kinds of Presence

Let's assume we have the following annotations (imports omitted):

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface Foo {}
```

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Repeatable(BarList.class)
public @interface Bar {}
```

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface BarList {
  Bar[] value();
}
```

Then if we have:

```java
@Foo
@BarList({@Bar, @Bar})
public class Parent {}
```

```java
public class Child extends Parent {}
```

The following is true:

1. `Foo` is *directly present* on `Parent`.
2. `Foo` is *present* on `Child` (because it's inherited)
3. `BarList` is *directly present* on `Parent`
4. `BarList` is *present* on `Child` (because it's inherited)
5. Both `Bar` annotations are *indirectly present* on `Parent` (because they're repeatable and in their container annotation)
6. Both `Bar` annotations are *associated* with `Child` (because they're inherited, repeatable, and in their container annotation)

Some additional notes:

- If an annotation is *directly present* on `E` then the annotation is also *present* on and *associated* with `E`
- If an annotation is *indirectly present* on `E` then the annotation is also *associated* with `E`
- An annotation is inherited if and only if:

  1. The annotation type is meta-annotated with [`java.lang.annotation.Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)
  2. The annotation is present on an ancestor **class** (annotation inheritance only applies to classes, not interfaces, methods, fields, etc.)
- When an annotation is inherited but is present on multiple classes throughout the class hierarchy then only the "most recent" annotation is found (i.e. the annotation closest to the bottom of the queried hierarchy)
- If an annotation is *present* on class `E`, but the annotation is not inheritable, then the annotation will not be *present* on nor *associated* with subclasses of `E`
- Repeatable annotations do not need to be explicitly placed in their corresponding container annotation. For example, the above could have used:

  ```java
  @Foo
  @Bar
  @Bar
  public class Parent {}
  ```

  The two `Bar` annotations are implicitly wrapped in their container annotation (i.e. `BarList`) by the compiler. That means the two `Bar` annotations are still *indirectly present* on `Parent` and *associated* with `Child`. However, this implicit wrapping only occurs if there is *more than one* of a repeatable annotation. So if there were only one `Bar` annotation then it would be *directly present* on `Parent` and *present* on `Child`.